# golang present use_playground=false prog.go:9:2: cannot find package

Tags: go

I try the golang present tool.

I embedd in my slide a source code with the following line:

```
.play simple/main.go /START OMIT/,/END OMIT/
```

The main.go is a simple program that imports a module that is not from the standard lib.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"
)

func main() {
    // START OMIT
    g := new(errgroup.Group)
    fmt.Println(g)
    // END OMIT
}
```

If I run present `present -use_playground=true` it works.

If I run present `present -use_playground=false` it throws the following error.

```
prog.go:7:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/xxx/go/src/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup (from $GOPATH)

Program exited: exit status 1
```

any help appreciated.